# android Programmatically set screen brightness and keep it

Tags: android

I'm trying to set the screen brightness from my app, but as soon the screen rotates (Auto-Rotate) my brightness is reset to the systems default brightness.

The code I'm using is following:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = 0.5f;
((Activity) context).getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
((Activity) context).startActivity(new Intent(context, DummyActivity.class));
```

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1970144&seqNum=9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your activity is restarting.
You can try adding your window settings code in onCreate of your activity.
Make sure that this code is added before setting  the view of the activity.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
     lp.screenBrightness = 0.5f;
     getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_id);
 }
```